# Min height of 90%?

Tags: html, css

I have a content div. I want it to be atleast 90% of the screen.

I currently have:

```
   min-height: 400px;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 400px;
```

in my #content div's css.

Changing to 90% did not work.

Is there some way to do this?

Essentially it will always run 90% down the screen unless something makes it bigger than 90%.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating a wrap that has height 100%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set html and body to fill 100% of the height, look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/KhCb6/

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#myDiv {
    min-height: 10px;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `height:auto !important` is killing it. Remove it. Also, I would suggest using this method:

```
height:90%;
min-height:400px;
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no other elements? Margin? Padding? Can you show an example of this happening?

Comment: #wrap
{
    height:100%;
}
#content
{
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
     min-height: 10px;
    height: 90%;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    
}


body
{
    height:100%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

Comment: The padding is most likely making the box take up the full thing. Try adding `box-sizing:border-box`.

Comment: No, an empty page is taking up about 10px, not even close to 90%.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you're going to have the content, you can fake this by letting the overflowed content have the same background. For example:

```
#mainDiv {
min-height: 10px;
height: 90%;
background-color: #ddd;
}

#mainDiv p {
background-color: #ddd;
}
```

This way, your overflowed content would "look like it's expanding" with the div. Not ideal, but this gets what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set min-height of Div ie min-height:90%;

```
#mainDiv {
min-height: 90%;
background-color: #ddd;
}
```